# Error in scale_linetype_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling

I'm trying to scale linetype manualy using `ggplot2` package. However, I recieve this error with no idea what's wrong.

Example:

```
group <- c("a", "b", "c")

ggplot() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 3, 
                 colour = group[1], 
                 linetype = group[1])) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 2, 
                 colour = group[2], 
                 linetype = group[2])) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1, 
                 colour = group[3], 
                 linetype = group[3])) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = "",
                      breaks = group, 
                      labels = c("This is group A", 
                                 "This is group B", 
                                 "This is group C"),
                      values = c("red", "purple", "gold")) + 
### until here everything works OK, but when I add scale_linetype_manual I get error
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "",
                        breaks = group, 
                        labels = c("This is group A", 
                                   "This is group B", 
                                   "This is group C"),
                        values = c("solied", "dotted", "dashed"))


Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_segments, x$x0, x$y0, x$x1, x$y1, x$arrow) : 
  invalid hex digit in 'color' or 'lty'
```

Is there any mistake in my syntax? Or is there any easier way how to change linetype and including this change into legend?

Comment: Typo: `"solied"` should be `"solid"`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, sorry for being stupid (: